# How to create Picture Library on office365 sharepoint using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, picture-library, sharepoint-library

Currently I have created SharePoint Hosted App (Picture Slider) in Office 365.I have created **picture Library Manually**, and now trying to create Picture Library using powershell in office 365.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PowerShell to create Sharepoint Picture Library:**

```
############################################################################################################################################ 
#Script that allows to create a new list in a SharePoint Online Site 
# Required Parameters: 
#  -> $sUserName: User Name to connect to the SharePoint Online Site Collection. 
#  -> $sPassword: Password for the user. 
#  -> $sCSOMPath: CSOM Assemblies Path. 
#  -> $sSiteUrl: SharePoint Online Site Url. 
#  -> $sListName: Name of the list we are going to create. 
#  -> $sListDescription: List description. 
############################################################################################################################################ 

$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread" 

#Definition of the function that allows to create a new view in a SharePoint Online list 
function Create-NewListSPO 
{ 
    param ($sCSOMPath,$sSiteUrl,$sUserName,$sPassword,$sListName,$sListDescription) 
    try 
    {    
        #Adding the Client OM Assemblies         
        $sCSOMRuntimePath=$sCSOMPath +  "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"         
        $sCSOMPath=$sCSOMPath +  "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"              
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMPath          
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMRuntimePath        

        #SPO Client Object Model Context 
        $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteUrl) 
        $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUserName, $sPassword)   
        $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials       

        Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green 
        Write-Host "Creating List $sListName in $sSiteUrl !!" -ForegroundColor Green 
        Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green         

        $spoWeb=$spoCtx.Web 
        $spoListCreationInformation=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation 
        $spoListCreationInformation.Title=$sListName 
        #https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype.aspx 
        $spoListCreationInformation.TemplateType=[int][Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplatetype]::PictureLibrary 
        $spoList=$spoWeb.Lists.Add($spoListCreationInformation) 
        $spoList.Description=$sListDescription 
        $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

        Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green 
        Write-Host "Lsita $sListName created in $sSiteUrl !!" -ForegroundColor Green 
        Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green   
        $spoCtx.Dispose() 
    } 
    catch [System.Exception] 
    { 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.ToString()    
    }     
} 

#Required Parameters 
$sSiteUrl = "https://<O365Domain>.sharepoint.com/<SPO_Site>" 
$sUserName = "<O365User>@<O365Domain>.onmicrosoft.com"  
$sListName= "<SPO_List_Name>" 
$sListDescription="<List Description>" 
#$sPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password: " -AsSecureString   
$sPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString "<SPO_Password>" -AsPlainText -Force 
$sCSOMPath="<SPO_Path>" 

Create-NewListSPO -sCSOMPath $sCSOMPath -sSiteUrl $sSiteUrl -sUserName $sUserName -sPassword $sPassword -sListName $sListName -sListDescription $sListDescription
```

In `$sCSOMPath` set the path for SharePoint Client dll.

Ref: [How to create a List in a SharePoint Online Site using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-create-a-List-in-a-2ff75523)

Answer (score 3):

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Start-SPAssignment -Global
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Web
$listTemplate = $SPWeb.ListTemplates["Picture Library"]
$SPWeb.Lists.Add($ListUrl,$Description,$listTemplate)
$list = $SPWeb.Lists[$ListUrl]
$list.Title = $ListTitle
$list.Update()
$SPWeb.Dispose()    
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 

if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Green 
} 
$web = $clientContext.Web
$templates = $clientContext.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)
$clientContext.Load($templates)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$template = $templates | Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq "PictureLibrary" }

$lci = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$lci.Title = "Custom Picture library"
$lci.TemplateFeatureId = $template.FeatureId
$lci.TemplateType = $template.ListTemplateTypeKind
$lci.DocumentTemplateType = $template.ListTemplateTypeKind

$lists = $clientContext.Web.Lists;
$clientContext.Load($lists);
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

$list = $lists.Add($lci)
$list.Update()
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```